Manga about people in world fighting a boy to get his seeds
This was a manga about a world where a high school boy is fought over by a group of people for his seeds.
I remember this is a comedy manga with adult jokes that made me laugh.

You could improve this Anime Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Literal seeds? Or do they mean his sperms?

Was the boy from Earth and did he get transported to another world?

Dandadan has aliens wanting human "banana" organs; male and female.
